# /*From CLR*/ in Java TreeMap implementation

Tags: java, clr

I was looking Java's (JDK 1.6_45) TreeMap code to understand a problem I was having and on few methods I saw a comment saying /** From CLR */.

I was under the impression that CLR is Microsoft terminology for its common runtime. Is CLR terminology used for Java as well? If not, then is there a common agreement to use each others implementation (after converting of-course) or is it just some auto generated comment?

Example

```
/** From CLR */
    private void fixAfterInsertion(Entry<K,V> x) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Java's `TreeMap` "borrowed" part of its implementation from [JabberNet's Tree](https://github.com/dib0/JabberNet/blob/master/Jabber-Net/bedrock/collections/Tree.cs), which is written in C# — [here the full C# source code](https://github.com/dib0/JabberNet/blob/master/Jabber-Net/bedrock/collections/Tree.cs).

Most probably one of the authors of the Java's `TreeMap` included the comment to reflect this fact (so "CLR" in the comment indeed means "Common Language Runtime").

Here a snippet [from Java's `TreeMap`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/TreeMap.java#2187):

```java
/** From CLR */
private void fixAfterDeletion(Entry<K,V> x) {
    while (x != root && colorOf(x) == BLACK) {
        if (x == leftOf(parentOf(x))) {
            Entry<K,V> sib = rightOf(parentOf(x));

            if (colorOf(sib) == RED) {
                setColor(sib, BLACK);
                setColor(parentOf(x), RED);
                rotateLeft(parentOf(x));
                sib = rightOf(parentOf(x));
            }

            if (colorOf(leftOf(sib))  == BLACK &&
                colorOf(rightOf(sib)) == BLACK) {
            ...
```

And here the corresponding snippet [from the JabberNet C# code](https://github.com/dib0/JabberNet/blob/master/Jabber-Net/bedrock/collections/Tree.cs#L628):

```c#
private void fixAfterDeletion(Node x)
{
    while ((x != root) && (colorOf(x) == NodeColor.BLACK))
    {
        if (x == leftOf(parentOf(x)))
        {
            Node sib = rightOf(parentOf(x));

            if (colorOf(sib) == NodeColor.RED)
            {
                setColor(sib, NodeColor.BLACK);
                setColor(parentOf(x), NodeColor.RED);
                rotateLeft(parentOf(x));
                sib = rightOf(parentOf(x));
            }

            if ((colorOf(leftOf(sib))  == NodeColor.BLACK) &&
                (colorOf(rightOf(sib)) == NodeColor.BLACK))
            ...
```

As you can see, the code is almost identical — except for indentation, node class name and syntax differences.

This is also true for other methods marked as `/** From CLR */`.

However, the Java code does *not* seem to be fully auto-generated from the C# code, cf. [this comment in the Java code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/TreeMap.java#2024):

```java
/**
 * Balancing operations.
 *
 * Implementations of rebalancings during insertion and deletion are
 * slightly different than the CLR version.  Rather than using dummy
 * nilnodes, we use a set of accessors that deal properly with null.  They
 * are used to avoid messiness surrounding nullness checks in the main
 * algorithms.
 */
```

Comment: This can't be true. That implementation of `TreeMap` dates back to Java 1.2 (1998). See source here: https://github.com/fanhongtao/JDK/blob/jdk_1.2.1/src/java/util/TreeMap.java
The first ever release of C# (version 1.0) was in 2002!

Comment: But CLR started earlier than that, approximately 1998.

Comment: Work on the CRL begun in June 98. Java 1.2 was released in December. Do you suggest that the team behind Java 1.2 copied a tree implementation from some unknown project at a different company that just got started 4 months before the release? Oh, and one of the very first things implemented in the CLR, just months after the several year long project was started was a tree? Take a look at Bing Zhao’s answer. It makes a LOT morse sense.

Comment: The code was not borrowed from C#. CLR in that context is short for Cormen, Leiserson and Rivest, authors of "Introduction to algorithms", as stated in the code comments: `Algorithms are adaptations of those in Cormen, Leiserson, and Rivest's Introduction to Algorithms.`

Answer (score 7):

"CLR" is an abbreviation of three persons, namely Cormen, Leiserson and Rivest, authors of the first edition of ***[Introduction to Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms)***.

EmirCalabuch answered in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21331561/5053214) that

> There is nothing peculiar in the TreeMap implementation of RBT. It closely follows the pseudocode given in CLRS's (Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest and Stein) book, which is what 99% of the implementations around do.

"CLRS" refers to the same book as "CLR" does. Since this kind of method closely follows ***[Introduction to Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms)***, being commented with `/** From CLR */` is reasonable.